# Jfiddle HTML Scroll Table Example Does Not Scroll Horizontally

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

trying my hands on the an html table with a fixed header from this [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/eZXtq/) link.

 From the site the table is to have a vertical and horizontal scroll. 

 The example table is shown below.
[image]

How when I run the code I get the following table.
[image]

My practice code is rendered below

Below is the code for the index.php  file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scroll.js'></script>

</head>
<body>

<header> 

</header> 


   <div class="outer-container">
        <div class="inner-container">
            <div class="table-header">
                <table id="headertable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="header-cell col1">One</th>
                            <th class="header-cell col2">Two</th>
                            <th class="header-cell col3">Three</th>
                            <th class="header-cell col4">Four</th>
                            <th class="header-cell col5">Five</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="table-body">
                <table id="bodytable">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                            <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Below is the javascript/JQuery scroll.js code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTableBody();
  $(window).resize(setTableBody);
  $(".table-body").scroll(function() {
    $(".table-header").offset({
      left: -1 * this.scrollLeft
    });
  });
});

function setTableBody() {
  $(".table-body").height($(".inner-container").height() - $(".table-header").height());
}
```

Below is the CSS code

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.outer-container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 300px;
  bottom: 40px;
}
.inner-container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table-header {
  position: relative;
}
.table-body {
  overflow: auto;
}
.header-cell {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: left;
  height: 40px;
}
.body-cell {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: left;
}
.col1,
.col3,
.col4,
.col5 {
  width: 120px;
  min-width: 120px;
}
.col2 {
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

My problem is that the table does not scroll horizontally like the jfiddle page.No error in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below,

It is working as expected

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTableBody();
  $(window).resize(setTableBody);
  $(".table-body").scroll(function() {
    $(".table-header").offset({
      left: -1 * this.scrollLeft
    });
  });
});

function setTableBody() {
  $(".table-body").height($(".inner-container").height() - $(".table-header").height());
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.outer-container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 300px;
  bottom: 40px;
}
.inner-container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table-header {
  position: relative;
}
.table-body {
  overflow: auto;
}
.header-cell {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: left;
  height: 40px;
}
.body-cell {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: left;
}
.col1,
.col3,
.col4,
.col5 {
  width: 120px;
  min-width: 120px;
}
.col2 {
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='scroll.js'></script>

</head>

<body>

  <header>

  </header>


  <div class="outer-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="table-header">
        <table id="headertable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="header-cell col1">One</th>
              <th class="header-cell col2">Two</th>
              <th class="header-cell col3">Three</th>
              <th class="header-cell col4">Four</th>
              <th class="header-cell col5">Five</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="table-body">
        <table id="bodytable">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
              <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
              <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```